# Can't install omnicomplete on gvim (Ubuntu)

Tags: vim, ubuntu

I download file to home folder into downloads, and extract it there. But when i try to run command `:helptags $HOME/.vim/doc` gvim shows error directory doesnt exist. Can someone tell me how to complete that installation succefully and where to extract those files from zip i downloaded from `http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: 
- Make sure you have a .vim folder in your home directory(/home/yourname/.vim)

- Extract the file in a directory.
- Copy all the files from there into .vim directory, and overwrite if your file manager asks about folder names.
- Do helptags.

Alternatively you can take a look at [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen), or check Ubuntu repositories for the plugin.

Comment: +1 for Pathogen. Once you have that set up, you can install most plugins by finding them on Github and just typing something like `git clone https://github.com/vim-scripts/OmniCppComplete.git`

Comment: Vundle is an alternative to Pathogen. Both are awesome. Vundle makes working with those pesky github repositories even easier.